# Кракозябры file_get_contents()

Tags: php, utf-8, кодировка

Да уж, вопрос на первый взгляд может показаться нубским, но разрешить его я не могу вот уже на протяжении 2 дней. Код:

```
header("Content-type: UTF-8");
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.m-dv.ru/catalog/id,3833/prohod.html");
echo $data;
```

У меня везде стоит UTF-8, сервер также выдает контент в этой кодировке, но что-то у нас с ним не складывается: на выходе получаются кракозябры..

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем тут может быть дело?

[***ПРИМЕР***](http://bot.lgg.ru/android/admin/parser.php)

Прошу помощи!

Comment: Текст через `iconv()` попробуйте пропустить с нужными кодировками. Проверь, в какой кодировке видит браузер сайт.

Comment: А покажите кракозябры, хотя бы кусочек?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Все ведь в UTF-8..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не "кракозябры", это zip-архив. Добавьте вместо своего

```
header("Content-type: UTF-8");
```

Вот эти строчки:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```

И кончатся Ваши двухдневные мучения...)

**UPDATE**

Еще вариант

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents("http://www.m-dv.ru/catalog/id,3833/prohod.html"), 10));
```

Скорее всего подойдет больше, если текст страницы надо дальше обрабатывать.

Comment: Ага, и никто не заметил, что на сервере gzip сжатие стоит :)

Comment: Что за извращения) Спасибо, это уже гораздо ближе к сути. Только вот страница теперь вовсе недоступна.

Comment: Вообще код рабочий, я проверял. Как именно проявляется "недоступность"?

Comment: Такая ошибка только на локальном хосте. Я забыл включить какие-то директивы в PHP.ini ?

Comment: Просто проверьте `ZLib`, должна быть просто включена.

Comment: Хм, это единственное, что необходимо включить? Просто ошибка исчезла, но снова gzip преобразуется не так( "кракозябры" ). Например, играет ли здесь роль **zlib.output_compression_level=-1** ?

Comment: Обновил ответ. С настройками `zlib` помочь не могу, но проблема точно в них.

Comment: О, все заработало! Спасибо вам. Очень помогли!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Вроде так пишется правильно + посмотри в какой кодировке файл сохранен.

ТС - заметь,каждый раз при получении страницы она разная! возможно что она запаковывается чем-то. Даже в твоем примере, обнови пару раз, контент будет разный всегда, пусть и кракозябрами!

Тут дело не в них, а в ответе сервера на твой запрос!

Comment: Да я так тоже указывал, только в мета-теге. Не работает..

Comment: Ок, даже если это так, что с этим делать?

Comment: Нужно понять что отдает сервак, а потом копать дальше.

Comment: Он всегда отдает в UTF-8 - это точно.

Comment: Вникни в суть ответа "Что отдает сервак" а не в какой кодировке отдает. Разницу видишь?

Comment: @Равнодушный, обнаружил сжатие на сервере.